# in_array and array_unique not working

Tags: php, unique-array

My code still displays the duplicate values, even after trying both functions `in_array` and `array_unique`. I get values from database. Some rows have multiple values. 
I want to break down those by commas and than remove duplicates. 
Please Help, Thanks In Advance.

```
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
   $mark=explode(',', $row['sku']);
   foreach($mark as $out) {
     if(!in_array($out, $array)){
     $array[] = $out;
     }
   }

}
$unique_array = array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR);
natsort($unique_array);
print_r($unique_array);
?>
```

Comment: Could you please format your code to help others understand it better?

Comment: I did, please check if it works for you now

Comment: That looks like `perl`. Tag it as such to get the right audience.

Comment: It really **is** PHP.

Comment: its php. i will edit

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code, which should do what you want: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4895a5b39c555835e378114eabc7ed78c6811285

```
<?php

// I create some sample data
$rows = [['sku' => 'a,b,c'], ['sku' => 'c,d,e'], ['sku' => 'e,f,g']];

$array = [];

// You want to replace this with your while loop
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $mark = explode(',', $row['sku']);

    foreach ($mark as $out) {
        if (!in_array($out, $array)) {
            array_push($array, $out);
        }
    }

}

// I don't think you need this here, because you already ensure that the array won't contain duplicates
$unique_array = array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR);

natsort($unique_array);
var_dump($unique_array);
var_dump($array);
```

So using your `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))` it should be like:

```
<?php

$array = [];
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $mark = explode(',', $row['sku']);

    foreach ($mark as $out) {
        if (!in_array($out, $array)) {
            array_push($array, $out);
        }
    }

}

natsort($unique_array);
var_dump($unique_array);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, i have tried editing my code, but doesnot works for me, can you check please                                                               while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($third)) {
$nmp[] = $row['sku'];
}

foreach ($nmp as $row) {
$mark=explode(',', $row);
foreach($mark as $out) {
        if (!in_array($out, $array, true)) {
            array_push($array, $out);
   echo $out;
        }
}

}


natsort($array);
foreach ($array as $color) {
echo $color.'<br />';
}

Comment: Could you update the original post with your code or create a new question if the problem is different? Could you also provide an example showing your problem, e.g., using http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com